# Pandas dataframe apply function to column strings based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove all instance of the string in col 'B' from col 'A', like so:

```
col A                 col B    col C
1999 toyota camry     camry    1999 toyota 
2003 nissan pulsar    pulsar   20013 nissan
```

How would I do this using pandas? If it was a fixed value (non-dependent on another column), I would use:

```
df['col C'] = df['col A'].str.replace('value-to-replace','')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given a `DataFrame` of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': ['1999 toyota camry', '2003 nissan pulsar'],
        'B': ['camry', 'pulsar']
    }
)
```

You can [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) over the row axis and perform the replacement:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda L: L.A.replace(L.B, ''), axis=1)
```

This'll give you:

```
                    A       B             C
0   1999 toyota camry   camry  1999 toyota 
1  2003 nissan pulsar  pulsar  2003 nissan
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a dataframe:

```
df

               col A    col B
0   1999 toyota camry   camry
1   2003 nissan pulsar  pulsar
```

Then you may proceed as follows:

```
df['col C'] = [el[0].replace(el[1],'') for el in zip(df['col A'],df['col B'])]
df

                col A   col B         col C
0   1999 toyota camry   camry   1999 toyota
1   2003 nissan pulsar  pulsar  2003 nissan
```